# How to group by how close rows are in time

Tags: sql, django, orm

Say I have a model that looks like:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User') 
    action = models.IntegerField(choices=ACTION_CHOICES)
    when = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to get all of the Actions for a user grouped by them being within 15 minutes of each other. Preferably in django's ORM if possible but if there is no other way, then PostgreSQL answers wouldn't be bad.

More clarification:

What I am looking for is along the lines of if `a` and `b` are 13 minutes apart, `b` and `c` are 10 minutes apart, `a` `b` and `c` would be grouped together even though `a` and `c` are 23 minutes apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, I'm assuming each subsequent action will be within 15 minutes of the last one in a sorted list of actions:

```
# sort by when in ascending order
actions = Action.objects.order_by('when')

group_dict = {}
action_list = []

count = 0
for action in actions:
    if action_list:
        diff = action.when - action_list[-1].when
        if diff.seconds <= 900: # 15 minutes in seconds
            action_list.append(action)
        else:
            group_dict[count] = action_list
            action_list = [action]
            count += 1
    else:
        action_list.append(action)

print group_dict
```

Comment: Unfortunately I was stuck using something in Python like this. I did a little research into doing it with SQL but most of it was overkill and I just added caching on top.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a time_length field on action, which would be set to the time since the previous action at create-time, if it's within your window, or NULL if it is not.  Then put a second field on action, action_group, with a unique id for the group.  Then in your report you can just GROUP BY action_group.